# Is it possible to create a GUI control that can be accessed from two Threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

in order to create a little 2D game from scratch, I'd like to create a panel on a WinForm and draw to it using a Graphics-object (btw, do I have to use a panel or could I just draw to the form directly? I know that you can do this, but where are the disadvantages?).

Now I want to continously run two loops in different threads. One thread should primary be assigned to do calculations and the other one should primary draw to the panel. In some cases however, both threads should be able to draw to the panel and that is were my problem occurs. As you know, an error occurs if you try to simply access a GUI control that was not created for that specific thread. I also don't want to always use a code like

```
if (control1.InvokeRequired)
{
control1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { control1.Text = string1; }));
}
```

because I'm really not familiar with this option. Is there a way to create my panel in a way so that both threads can easily access it or is this impossible?

Comment: My suggestion would be for you to become familiar with that option. When working in multiple threads you will need to use callbacks to access any other threads.

Comment: Revise your approach. First and foremost: at no time two threads should be messing with rendering. Rendering is one task that one thread should do. You also shouldn't be afraid of code you don't understand; research it. And you shouldn't draw using a Graphics object if you want anything that resembles performance.

Comment: What other options are there for drawing?

Comment: You primary thread, or a dedicated thread should be used for drawing. Your calculation threads can call to the draw thread and it can prioritize the draw actions internally.

Comment: @Joey You need to do all your drawing on one thread, one that you are using for your GUI. If you then need to do calculations in one or more threads then keep these separate, and when an event occurs (e.g a thread finishes calculating) then the thread that is rendering needs to pick this up and draw an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to create my panel in a way so that both threads can easily access it or is this impossible?

No. You don't want to do that. There is a lot of history behind why in Windows, but the short answer is, the GUI thread should be doing all of the drawing and accessing all of the controls.

> btw, do I have to use a panel or could I just draw to the form directly? I know that you can do this, but where are the disadvantages?

WinForms in general is not the best option for high-performance drawing - it does all of it's drawing by the CPU instead of the GPU. You can use WPF for some hardware assisted drawing, but the usual approach is to go down the DirectX approach and using something like DirectDraw or Direct2D. However depending on what your expectations and needs are, WinForms may work just fine.

To answer your actual question, there isn't much of a difference between drawing directly on the Form itself vs. a Panel.

> because I'm really not familiar with this option.

I like CodeCaster's comment on this. Spend a bit of time on it and it shouldn't be too difficult to get the hang of. The "GUI thread" (main thread, whatever you want to call it) operates on a message pump. Think of it as a queue with different priorities. The GUI thread just spends its time in a message loop handling items in its queue. "Set this control's text to that", "Draw this here", "Repaint because the Window was resized", etc. What your `Control.Invoke` boils down to is adding an item on the queue for the GUI thread to do.

Comment: Thanks for that edit, too. It cleared the GUI thread thing up pretty good for me!